# How to apply timeout to core threads within ThreadPoolExecutor in Java5

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

My question is as straight and simple as the title illustrates, put it another way, what is the equivalent method in jdk 1.5 of the allowCoreThreadTimeOut in jdk1.6? Because I do need all idle core threads released after, say 30s, if no more new tasks come in betwwen, thanks for any helpful pointers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the 1.6 functionality in 1.5, then you can use the [backport-util-concurrent](http://backport-jsr166.sourceforge.net/) library which retrofits newer concurrency stuff into older Java versions as a 3rd-party library.

Specifically, you can get the 1.6 functionality in your 1.5 app.

Comment: Anything I can do w/o 3rd libraries involved? Since it really is not the best solution for my case, thanks!

Comment: If that property isn't in 1.5, then you're out of luck.  A bunch of enhancements were added in the 1.6 concurrency classes.